# Error: Switch from SKScene to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, view, sprite-kit

I am trying to switch from a SKScene to another ViewController but the following error occurs:

Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Here is the hierarchy in my main.storyboard: 
InitialViewController > MainViewController > GameViewController (that includes the scene).

Also I have tried to perform a segue. It was linked from the initialViewController to the mainViewController. Nothing happened.

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuViewController")
self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Why do you want to switch from a skscene to another viewcontroller? What do you want to do in that view controller?

Comment: @Silas33, you can manage whole project with just one GameViewController. You only need scenes to present. Try to share your objective in your question.